# Probability of indepence events

Tags: probability

I am learning probability with "An introduction to mathematical statistics and its applications.". Larsen and Marx. Great book. I understood bayes and some others methods more complex than this question:

> Dana and Cathy are playing tennis. The probability that Dana wins at least one out of two games is $0.3$. What is the probability that Dana wins at least one out of four?

The answer is $0.51$ but I could not reach that. I know that the probability of winning none is $P(\text{winning none of two})= 1-0.3=0.7$. But I do not know how to connect that with the probability of winning 1 of 4, 2 of 4, 3 of 4 and 4 of 4. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Assuming the games are independent, and given $P(\text{winning none of 2})=0.7$, then from this you can work out what the probability of winning none of $4$ games is. So you can work out the probability of winning at least one is, since this is the complement of losing $4$ games.

---

**Edit:**

$P(\text{winning none of 4})=[P(\text{winning none of 2})]^2=[0.7]^2=0.49$.

So $P(\text{winning at least 1 of 4})=1-0.49=0.51$

Comment: Thanks John. I can not see the 0.51 yet. I got 0.21 and I do not know what I am not seeing. thanks.

Comment: I have edited to make this clearer :)

Answer (score 0):

$$P(\text{Winning at least 1 out of 4}) = 1- P(\text{Losing all 4}) $$
$$= 1 - P(\text{Losing the first 2}) \cdot P(\text{Losing the last 2})$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hi Harto. Thanks. I got to 0.21 but the book says the answer is 0.51 I do not know what is missing...

Comment: The last line equals $1-0.7 \cdot 0.7 = 1- 0.49$.

Answer (score 0):

P(losing first 2)=.7, P(losing last 2)=.7.  Since the events are independent P(losing all 4)=.49.  Therefore P(winning at least 1)=.51.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot Herb!